# 18.04 super+shift to change language

Tags: 18.04, input-language, shortcut-keys

I am trying to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change the language with no success on Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome-session-fallback

I tried gnome tweaks but did not succeed.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you got other languages set?

Comment: Yes I can change the language using the default binding super+space